# Mango seedling has stem and leaves but no root!

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, fruit-trees, germination, seedlings

I've got two problems with my mango seedlings:

Problem #1

I have germinated a mango seed in water, it now has a decent stem and healthy-looking leaves. It is currently still in water, indoors, in the brightest spot in my house getting maximum direct sunlight (I live in the UK).

When the root first germinated (2-3 months ago) I accidentally snapped it off while refilling the water. The root never grew back, however several stems since germinated and it has continued to grow leaves rapidly!!

I am at the point now where I am wanting to plant it into a pot of (ericaceous) compost however there is no root system. There is a bulbous growth, which I assume is acting as a root. I don't think it would survive in soil. Is there any method I could use to force the growth of roots? Would planting it out do this? Or fertilizer (I have only used boiled tap-water up to this point)?

See attached pictures - my plan was to wait for another root to grow but I have been waiting for months!!

Problem #2

I have another mango seedling with the opposite problem. All root and no stem growth!! It germinated in water at a similar time (2-3 months ago) and I have it kept in the same position with maximum sunlight.

The root has grown extensively and seems healthy as far as I can tell (see pictures). There is one small stem which seemed to have leaves sprouting however it hasn't grown in a long time.

Should I keep this seedling in water until the stem and leaves grow? Or hope another stem pops up soon? Or should I plant it out into (ericaceous) compost?

See attached pictures - my plan was to keep it in water until a sturdy stem and leaves were produced before I planted it out.

Any advice much appreciated! 
Thanks, Richard

Pictures of seedling #1
[image]
[image]
[image]

Pictures of seedling #2
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Mangos are such an interesting plant to grow from seed. I have a few seeds that I started in paper towels and one of them started dying and for some reason I thought I should cut it to encourage it to branch or something (I really don't remember what happened). After a few weeks it was still a sad looking seed with a single stem and nothing else but the following week I noticed it had grown two main little branches all the way from the joint at the seed and it was growing new leaves and even a few other little things... So now it is like shown in the picture. I wonder if your seed with long ro